# Finding DOM elements in a page on site built from Salesforce

Tags: lightning, javascript

Sorry if this seems ignorant.

Trying to automate my interactions as a user of a non-publicly visible site associated with a US state health department.

It's built on Salesforce.  I find that my standard document.querySelector, and so on, seem not to work.  In Chrome, right-click on the item and copy its selector; insert that appropriately into the function; execute but the result is always null.  Array functions return .length = 0.

Is there 'extra' stuff one needs to know when trying to find DOM elements in a Salesforce page?

Comment: P.S. I don't know why you're trying to do what you're trying to do. You might want to explain the background of your question (see the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) page for more details). You can [edit] in additional details, and we'll be happy to help you the best we can. I noticed you're new here, so I'd like to also invite you to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. This will hopefully help you have the best possible experience here. I hope you enjoy your time here on SFSE!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the configuration of the page, it is either using [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm) (LS) or [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/security_lwsec_intro) (LWS). These services prevent components from accessing data outside their own namespace. This allows components from different developers to coexist on the same page without having to use complicated sandboxing techniques to prevent security leaks and data breaches.

Further, these pages utilize the [Lightning Web Runtime](https://lwc.dev) (LWR), which uses [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) technology from the [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) standard, using the "closed" model. This means that a parent's CSS cannot affect the insides of a child component except in a controlled manner, cannot access private properties and methods of that child, and cannot access a child's DOM children.

This is all done in the same of security and reliability. Developer A cannot possibly make a component that can completely manipulate Developer B's components. This is again a design consideration to allow multiple developers to create components that can coexist on the same page, but cannot be unduly influenced to do things it shouldn't do.

This is pretty much bad news for whatever it is you're trying to do. It is rather difficult to even inspect your own code at runtime, much less for anything else to. If your user is enabled for [Debug Mode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.debug_mode_enable), it enables a source map for your components, which makes debugging easier, but you still can't just randomly access the DOM programmatically.

On the plus side, you can get the [Lightning Inspector](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_use.htm), which allows you to see a lot of the internals of a Lightning App. This may help you gain understanding of how the app works, but you still won't be able to arbitrarily query components in a script.

Comment: Thanks - useful, even if in the negative.

So let me ask that a different way - is there any way of programmatically automating interactions with a Salesforce page?  Or should I have understood that the answer is still No?

Comment: @patfla like sfdxfox asked, why are you doing this? Is it for UI testing? If so, consider adopting [UTAM](https://utam.dev/salesforce/introduction).

Comment: We're closing out medical cases - much of which is rote and can be automated.  The first task: find a date in one field in a web form and take the values of two checkboxes on the same form, then set various dropdowns from other fields appropriately.  Can't submit just yet because the case still needs a note composed by the clerk that varies.  However, automating just the first part of the task would be very helpful.  This all occurs in a single, very long, Salesforce page.

Comment: Why not do this directly in the underlying database?  This is part of a state's healthcare infrastructure (bureaucracy), we don't have access to the database(s), but we can interact with the web representation of the data - to some extent - as we like.

Comment: @patfla Given the design of the security, I'm pretty sure it's impossible or very nearly so. The security layer is basically designed to prevent one of the things you're trying to do. That said, maybe you could try a URL hack: `recordIdhere/edit?defaultFieldValues=FieldName=fieldValue,FieldName2=fieldValue2` or something.

Comment: @patfla Of if there's custom components involved, it might look like `componentName?c__FieldName=fieldValue&c__FieldName2=fieldValue2`. I think it would be worth investigating the URL mechanisms instead.

Comment: Thanks - those look like useful suggestions.  I'll study what you've written and try things out when I get the cycles to get back to this particular problem.